# Spring MVC Missing URI template variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a `Controller` class with a function that saves a record to the Database. I am passing several parameters to the `Controller` function however i think i may be writing the `@RequestMapping` incorrectly. Under is the code

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="createRoadBlock.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody Integer createRoadBlock(@RequestParam String purpose, @RequestParam String userName,
                                              @RequestParam  int status, @RequestParam double latAdd,
                                              @RequestParam double longAdd, HttpServletRequest request,  
                                              HttpServletResponse response) {

         int roadBlockId = 0;
        try{

            roadBlockId = roadBlockManager.saveRoadBlock(purpose, userName, status,latAdd,longAdd);
            logger.info("Create Road Block Successful roadBlockId "+ roadBlockId);

            return roadBlockId;

        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Exception Occured In Road Block Controller "+e.getMessage());
            return roadBlockId;

        } 

     }
```

**Ajax Request**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'createRoadBlock.htm',
    contentType:"application/json",
    async:false,
    cache:false,
        data:{purpose:f_purpose, userName:f_userName,status: f_status,latAdd: f_latAdd, longAdd:f_lngAdd},
    dataType:'json'

    }).success(function(recordId){ 
                console.log('Road Block created with id ' + recordId);
    });
```

**Error Log**

```
Controller [com.crimetrack.web.RoadBlockController]
Method [public java.lang.Integer com.crimetrack.web.RoadBlockController.createRoadBlock(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,double,double,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]

org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'purpose' is not present
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`@PathVariable` is used to tell Spring that part of the URI path is a value you want passed to your method. Is this what you want, or are the variables supposed to be form data posted to the URI?

If you want form data, use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`.

If you want `@PathVariable`, you need to specify placeholders in the `@RequestMapping` entry to tell Spring where the path variables fit in the URI. For example, if you want to extract a path variable called `contentId`, you would use:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/whatever/{contentId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

**Edit**: Additionally, if your path variable could contain a '.' and you want that part of the data, then you will need to tell Spring to grab everything, not just the stuff before the '.':

`@RequestMapping(value = "/whatever/{contentId:.*}", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

This is because the default behaviour of Spring is to treat that part of the URL as if it is a file extension, and excludes it from variable extraction.

Comment: The data is passed via an ajax request as json so i may need to use @RequestMapping? In your example i am seeing you passing one parameter i would like to know how do your write several parameters will it be @RequestMapping(value = "/id/{param1,param2,param3...}". Also is 'whatever' the name of your parameter?

Comment: Do you have control over what the ajax is requesting? If so, then using RequestParam with query parameters in the URI is going to be much easier. Personally, I have had hours of pain with @PathVariable and am only using it for one variable at a time.

Comment: yes i do have control over the ajax request. Thanks however how would i type multiple parameters in the URI?

Comment: Oh RequestParam there is no need to include it in the URI?

Comment: You could either build a URI with the parameters like this: /createRoadBlock.htm?purpose=abc&userName=def&status=1&latAdd=-33.8675&longAdd=151.2070 or you could post the values as data.

Comment: RequestParam does not require you to specify any special placeholders in the RequestMapping - your existing one would work.

Comment: i updated the code however i am getting the same error what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I am getting a new error see my error log Required String parameter 'purpose' is not present however i can see in the firebug console the data being posted. However i am getting an HTTP status 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect from the browser

Comment: Is your ajax posting to something like this: /createRoadBlock.htm?purpose=abc&userName=def&status=1&latAdd=-33.8675&longAdd=1‌​51.2070

Comment: Yes it looks like this purpose=%22sdfsdfsdfsdf%22&userName=%22jeff%22&status=0&latAdd=10.52291894538631&longAdd=-61.3861083984375

Comment: i will include the ajax function above

Comment: Don't specify json as the content type. And only specify it as the data type if that's what your controller is returning.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer to this question from a couple years later!

Comment: @Jason Unrelated - an upvote ... as your answer to that newbie question on "continue" was the *only* one really answering the question. You shouldnt have deleted it ...

Comment: FYI: The annotation is case-sensitive! I looked for a while until I noticed a capitalised letter...

Comment: Yes. This helped me fixing a mistake where I used `@PathVariable` instead of `@RequestParam`. Silly.

Answer (score 36):

I got this error for a stupid mistake, the variable name in the @PathVariable wasn't matching the one in the @RequestMapping

For example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/whatever/{**contentId**}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public … method(@PathVariable Integer **contentID**){
}
```

It may help others

Comment: God... this helped me. I had 
 @PostMapping(value = "/folders/{foldername}")
method[...](@PathVariable String folderName)
That "N" on uppercase was the trick

Comment: Same Stupid Mistake here :|

Comment: eh, same stupid mistake. thank you very much for posting this

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that the name of the **parameter** from the method was **different** from the one passed **in @GetMapping**.
Those should be **identical**, otherwise there will be this kind of silent error.

```java
@GetMapping("/{formId}") // Must be the same as the PathVariable
    public ResponseEntity<Form> getFormById(@PathVariable Long formId){
        return new ResponseEntity<Form>(this.formsService.getById(formId), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This error may happen when mapping variables you defined in REST definition do not match with @PathVariable names.

Example:
Suppose you defined in the REST definition

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{appId}", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
```

Then during the definition of the function, it should be

```
public ResponseEntity<List> getData(@PathVariable String appId)
```

This error may occur when you use any other variable other than defined in the REST controller definition with @PathVariable.
Like, the below code will raise the error as ID is different than appId variable name:

```
public ResponseEntity<List> getData(@PathVariable String ID)
```